# NLG | T5 Paraphrase results are not creative enough

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, sentence-transformers, nlg

I've tried to use pre-trained model to create paraphrases of sentences,
Even after trying to correlate top_p and top_k the result paraphrases were almost the same as the original sentence.
I would like to get results that look completely different (eg. third person talking about this topic or to point an event that illustrates this topic.)

Below is an example of three sentences that express the same idea in different words:

1. Looking within is the best way to start solving the challenges in our lives.
2. People who are looking for solutions to their problems in the world around them will always continue to look for solutions.
3. The first step in healing our pain lies in our ability to "look in the mirror".
   Do you think it possible is to achieve those results with more effort on fine tuning or correlation?

models I've tried:

"ramsrigouthamg/t5_paraphraser": https://huggingface.co/ramsrigouthamg/t5_paraphraser

"Vamsi/T5_Paraphrase_Paws": https://huggingface.co/Vamsi/T5_Paraphrase_Paws

Comment: Probably not possible, the system will always be limited by the examples it knows from training, and naturally the easiest way to produce a correct paraphrase is to keep it close to the original sentence.

Comment: how about dropping some words from the first sentence of the training data instances? that way the models learns to recover those in a paraphrased or exact way. However, it might learn that it always need to add something to the first sentence. Also, you can get a larger training set.